# Newton step for ${\min}_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \ \sum_{i=1}^n -\ln(1 + \eta_i x_i) \ $ s.t. $A x \leq b$; $-x \leq 0$ to be used in primal-dual

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I have a following problem on hand.

**P1:**
\begin{align}
\text{minimize}_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \quad & \sum_{i=1}^n -\ln(1 + \eta_i x_i) \equiv -e^T \ln(e + \eta \odot x)  \\
\text{subject to }\quad &  Ax \leq b\\
& -x \leq 0 ,
\end{align}
where $A \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^{m \times n}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}_{++}^{m \times 1}$, $\eta \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n \times 1}$, and $e$ is all-ones vector.

**Question:**

**Is my Newton step correct (please see below)?**

(it is a part of the primal-dual interior point method).

Your suggestions/feedback will be highly appreciated.

---

***Partial attempt***

Reformulating the above problem **P1** such that 
\begin{align}
\text{minimize}_{x , y} \quad & e^T \ln(e + \eta \odot x) := f(x)  \\
\text{subject to }\quad &  Ax + y = b\\
& -y, -x \leq 0 .
\end{align}

Now forming the Lagrangian ($u \geq 0$, $v \geq 0$, and $w \in \mathbb{R}^m$),
\begin{align}
L_a(x,y,u,v,w) := f(x) - u^T x - v^T y - w^T(Ax + y - b) .
\end{align}

The [perturbed](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/convexopt/lectures/primal-dual.pdf) KKT conditions can be summarized as following:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L_a}{\partial x} = 0 \Longrightarrow \nabla f(x) - u - A^T w &= 0 \\
\frac{\partial L_a}{\partial y} = 0 \Longrightarrow -v - w &= 0 \\
U x - \tau e &= 0 \\
V y - \tau e &= 0 \\
Ax + y - b &= 0 \\
-y, -x &\leq 0 \ ,
\end{align}
where $U = {\rm Diag}(u)$ and $V = {\rm Diag}(v)$ are diagonal matrices.

Now the Newton step can be shown as

\begin{align}
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\nabla^2f(x)  &  0  & -I   &  0  & -A^T\\
0             &  0  &  0   & -I  & -I   \\
U             &  0  &  X   &  0  & 0   \\
0             &  V  &  0   &  Y  & 0   \\
A             &  I  &  0   &  0  & 0   \\
\end{array}
\right]
\ 
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\Delta x\\
\Delta y\\
\Delta u\\
\Delta v\\
\Delta w
\end{array}
\right]
&= 
\ -\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\nabla f(x) - u - A^T w\\
-v - w\\
Ux - \tau e \\
Vy - \tau e\\
Ax + y - b
\end{array}
\right]
\end{align}
where $0$ corresponds to all-zeros matrix of appropriate size and $I$ denotes an identity matrix of appropriate size.

Answer (score 0):

My answer maybe off-topic as you ask explicitly for a primal-dual interior point algorithm. If you are open for another solver you could try CVX which should work for your problem: http://cvxr.com/cvx/doc/CVX.pdf

CVX is a solver for convex optimization problems with an interface for Matlab. You have to "fit" your problem into the CVX-framework using the sum_log(x) function.

The optimization problem is indeed convex as you have convex constraints and a convex target function.

Please ask if you need further help.

Comment: I know CVX. But I want to learn the primal-dual method. For me at least  I understand more to understand how things work